# how to apply work item customisation to both old form & new form in TFS 2017?

Tags: tfs

In TFS 2017 [new form layout](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/manage-new-form-rollout) is introduced for work items. In my current project, I am customising the work items and it is applied only to the old form but not to the new form. How can the customisation be uniform in both the forms?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For TFS 2017, it has the new form. To custom the new form, you need to export the workitem definition file and find the `<WebLayout>` node, do customization under these node. Then changes will show on the new form. If you still customize under  node, it changes the old form and won't have effect on new form.

For example, add a control for a custom field:

```
<WebLayout>
       <SystemControls>
          <Control Type="FieldControl" FieldName="custom.field" Label="FieldTest" />
       </SystemControls>
</WebLayout>
```

For more information about custom new form in TFS 2017, please refer to this document: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/weblayout-xml-elements#customize-the-web-layout

Comment: In the work item xml structure we have two layouts. <Layout> for Old form and <WebLayout> for New form.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add custom fields or controls to the `<SystemControls>` element. Adding custom fields to the element results in a validation error on import. Removing predefined fields has no effect.

To clarify a little further: If you want the old form and the new form to look similar (or at least have similar fields on them), you have to add the field to both layouts (`<Layout>` and `<WebLayout>`) separately. There is no way of syncing them automatically.

As a side note: The TFS Power Tools 2017 do not support the new `<WebLayout>`, yet. So you have to edit the XML files by hand.